# finding a bijective map from $ F(m,n)\times F(k,n)$ to $F(m+k,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, hilbert-spaces, inverse

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

> For $A=(A_1,...,A_n) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^n$ and $m,k\in \mathbb{N}^*$. I want to show that
>     $$\sum_{h\in F(m,n)} A_h^*\left(\sum_{g\in F(k,n)} A_g^* A_{g}\right) A_{h}=\sum_{f\in F(m+k,n)} A_f^* A_{f}\; ??$$
>   where $F(m,n)$  the set of all functions $f$ from $\{1,2, ... , m\} $ to the set  $\{1.2...,n\}$. For $g\in F(m,n)$, we set $A_g:=A_{g(1)}\cdots A_{g(m)}$.

I try as follows:

$$
\sum_{h\in F(m,n)} A_h^*\left(\sum_{g\in F(k,n)} A_g^* A_{g}\right) A_{h}=\sum_{h \in F(m,n), g \in F(k,n)} (A_{g\ast h})^* A_{g \ast h},
$$

where $g \ast h$ is a function from $ F(m,n)\times F(k,n)$ to $F(m+k,n)$. I'm facing difficulties to give the expression of $g \ast h$ in order to show that it is a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an operation $\star$ such that for $f=g\star h$, $A_{f}$ is 
$A_g A_h=A_{g(1)}\cdots A_{g(m)}A_{h(1)}\cdots A_{h(k)}$. This means that

$$
\begin{array}{l}
f(1)=g(1), \cdots,f(m)=g(m),\\ 
f(m+1)=h(1), \cdots,f(m+k)=h(k), 
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$

And indeed, (1) does define a bijection from $ F(m,n)\times F(k,n)$ to $F(m+k,n)$
(it is just a concatenation when you think about it).

Comment: I think that $\star$ has the following inverse denoted $G\colon F(m+k,n)\longrightarrow F(m,n)\times F(k,n)$. If $f\in F(m+k,n)$, define $G_1(f)\in F(m,n)$ by $G_1(f)(j)=f(j)$ and define $G_2(f)\in F(k,n)$ by $G_2(f)(j)=f(j-m)$. Then, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}G\colon&F(m+k,n)&\longrightarrow&F(m,n)\times F(k,n)\\&f&\mapsto&\bigl(G_1(f),G_2(f)\bigr).\end{array}$$ But I facing difficulties to show that $G=\star^{-1}$.

Comment: I completely agree about your $G_1$ and $G_2$. The statement $G=\star^{-1}$ is equivalent to $G_1(g \star h)=g$ and $G_2(g\star h)=h$ and $G_1(f) \star G_2(f)=f$. Which of the three do you find difficult to show ?

Comment: Thank you it is clear.